# EDIT Single ROW in database from html form

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I want to edit single line not all, but now i add ID and now he do nothing, nothing change :(, before i give him ID, they edit all rows.

variables

```
$titletxt = ($_POST['title_txt']);
$value1 = ($_POST['value1_txt']);
$value2 = ($_POST['value2_txt']);
$ID = ($_POST['id']);

<?php
if( isset($_POST['edit']) ){
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hanza");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Neizdevas savienoties ar MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql="UPDATE dati SET title='$titletxt', value1='$value1', value2='$value2' WHERE ID = '$ID'";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo '<script>
    alert(" Ieraksts ir veiksmigi labots! ");

    window.location.href = "index.php";
    </script>';
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

That code is from form and i show results from database.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="td_opt">Title</td>
            <td class="td_opt">Value 1</td>
            <td class="td_opt">Value 2</td>
            <td class="td_opt">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
            <td class="td_title"><input type="text" name="title_txt" value=""></td>
            <td class="td_value"><input type="text" name="value1_txt" value=""></td>
            <td class="td_value"><input type="text" name="value2_txt" value=""></td>
            <td class="td_value"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hanza");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Neizdevas savienoties ar MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dati");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $row['title'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $row['value1'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $row['value2'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><button name='edit' class='frm_btns'>Edit</button></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </table>
    <div class="atp"></div>
    <button class="frm_btns" name="pievienot">New</button> // add new row
</form>
```

Maybe some variable is not corect to edit only one row?

Comment: UPDATE dati SET title='$titletxt', value1='$value1', value2='$value2' WHERE ID = ''
0 row(s) updated.

Answer (score 1):

what i can see . you have not given any name to

```
   // echo "<input type='hidden' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>";
```

so you will not get value in $_POST['id']

this element it should be name as id.

before update you should check if id is not blank.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your html you have used button the values of type button will not send to server instead you need to use `type="submit"`

```
echo "<td><button name='edit' class='frm_btns'>Edit</button></td>";// is wrong
```

Therefore it is not passing your if check because `$_POST['edit']` is not set

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){.... }
```

change button to submit

```
echo "<td><input name='edit' class='frm_btns' type='submit' value='Edit'/></td>";
```

Also you have missed to add the names to your `input` elements you just have assigned the values, name them also like

```
echo "<input name='id' type='hidden' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>"; ...for remaining elements also
```

Comment: When i give all names, and now i add new line, they copy first line and i cant add diferrent information and i cant edit ;/, something goes wrong with ID

Comment: Because you are doing wrong all fields are in loop and with same name you have to make a single form for each record if want to know how then let me know i will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
```

in this line there is no value is set for the argument id.

Please make sure you are setting the proper value for "id" before the form submit. (Using javascript)

Also I have noticed that you are using a button to edit. So make sure you are invoking a click event to set id and submit form.

As a suggestion you have to specify a value attribute for each row button. So it will be easy to retrieve the currently clicked "row id" by using getAttribute() property.

```
<button name='edit' class='frm_btns' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>Edit</button>
```